# matar todos os processos netbeans ao mesmo tempo

Tags: netbeans

Olá

Minha pergunta não é  diretamente ligada à programação, mas está relacionada e creio que vai ajudar muita gente.

O problema é o seguinte: Estou trabalhando com servidor e sockets no Netbeans e toda vez que executo testes abro 5 ou mais threads.

Na hora de fechá-los tenho que clicar no "x" de cada um, e depois confirmar a ação.

Nada muito grave, mas após 2 horas de testes já tô de saco cheio de ter encerrado uns 200 processos 1 por 1 hehe

Existe algum atalho que feche todos os processos sendo executados no momento??

Me refiro aos seguintes processos (print do Netbeans):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Se tiver utilizando Windows, pode fazer isso pelo prompt usando o comando:

```
taskkill /f /im [nome_do_processo]
```

Comment: Mas dessa forma eu teria que matar 1 a 1, assim como estou fazendo agora e ainda teria que acessar o cmd, ia me atrasar mais ainda. Procuro algum comando dentro da própria IDE

Comment: Entedi... os nomes dos processos são diferentes ?

Comment: São sim. Editei o post com um print dos processos e seus nomes